# Is AWS cognito client side authentication secure

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito

I am using ***AWS Cognito*** for authentication in my application. Cognito provides fully client-side authentication. But, we need to store credentials in `.env` file which is accessible from the browser.

Is it secure to use AWS Cognito for authentication, if I am building an enterprise application and security is important for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For AWS cognito the authentication happens at server side. Not on the client side. At the client side we are creating the opportunity for the user to log via his credentials, then the credentials will be sent to AWS Cognito for authentication. Which results in a accept or reject.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito itself is a service that you can build a secure identity foundation on - but not in the way you're proposing it.

Storing static credentials to 3rd party APIs in something that can be easily accessed by (un)authenticated users is a **terrible security practice**.

The security of Cognito is not your biggest problem, my advice would be to first find a better solution for your static credentials. Sometimes static credentials like API keys can't be avoided, but **you should never expose them to your end users**. Store them in something like the AWS Secrets Manager or the Systems Manager Parameter Store and retrieve them when you need them. Only store them in memory if possible and never send them to your clients.

Comment: But, the way and all tutorials present on the internet and YouTube, use the same method for Cognito. They either put **secret keys** directly in the source code or the `env` file(eg. React). Both of them is accessible by any end-user.

Comment: At any point in time, we should not bring the `secret keys` to the end-user. By, using these keys, any user can log in to the system.

Comment: I can't speak about the creators of all these tutorials, but the way you'd do it securely is that you have unauthenticated users redirected to the Cognito UI, where they can then login and receive a signed JSON Web Token, which they can then pass along on calls to the API Gateway or something like that to authenticate themselves. All the information the client needs for that is a client id of an app client in Cognito as well as the User Pool Id, neither of which are secrets.

Comment: Storing client credentials in code is something you can do for a quick demo, but not in production.